# Random assigning of numbers in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.5

I'm mapping a employee number to a 13 digit card number. Card number should be in a range between 9353500001234 and 9353500501234.

Is there any inbuilt function to map a random number from this range to a employee number. Ex employee number 5001 should be assigned to 9353500500934? Also once assigned, is it possible to pass the employee number to a function to get the corresponding card number assigned?

Comment: So you want a bi-directional mapping, where one number encodes another and you can get from one to the other without any lookup table? But one number should be pseudorandom-looking? Or is it OK to use a mapping table here?

Comment: It's okay to have a lookup table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although, in theory, one could generate a bijective function between the domains 1..500000 and 9353500001234...9353500501234, in practice, the easiest way is just to create a map (in the mathematical sense), and `SELECT` from it.

That is, you would start by creating a table to store pairs of `(employee_id, card_number)`:

```
CREATE TABLE employee_card
(
    employee_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    card_number BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE 
) ;
```

Given that table, we fill it with all possible employee_id and card_number, randomly shuffling the card_numbers. We do that by means of the [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES) set returning function, together with [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE), using a [`random()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-RANDOM-TABLE)ly sorted [window (over clause)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS):

```
INSERT INTO employee_card (employee_id, card_number)
SELECT
    row_number() over(order by random()) AS employee_id, employee_card
FROM
    -- generate card_numbers
    generate_series(9353500001234, 9353500501234) AS s(employee_card)
```

We add some indexes to get data in an optimal way:

```
-- Indexes to ease retrieving the data from this table
CREATE INDEX idx_employee_card_card_number ON employee_card(card_number, employee_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_employee_card_employee_id ON employee_card(employee_id, card_number);
VACUUM ANALYZE employee_card;
```

At this point, if you want to have two functions, they are just `SELECT`s from the previous table:

```
-- Get card_number given employee_id
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION card_number_from_employee_id(_employee_id integer) 
    RETURNS BIGINT
    IMMUTABLE
    STRICT
    LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
    SELECT card_number FROM employee_card WHERE employee_id = _employee_id ;
$$ ;

-- Get employee_id given card_number
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION employee_id_from_card_number(_card_number BIGINT)
    RETURNS INTEGER
    IMMUTABLE
    STRICT
    LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
    SELECT employee_id FROM employee_card WHERE card_number = _card_number ;
$$ ;
```

You can now test a few employee_ids, and retrieve card numbers. The card numbers should look random:

```
SELECT 
    employee_id, card_number_from_employee_id(employee_id)
FROM
    generate_series(10001, 10010) AS s(employee_id) ;
```

```
employee_id | card_number_from_employee_id
----------: | ---------------------------:
      10001 |                9353500008121
      10002 |                9353500281438
      10003 |                9353500124657
      10004 |                9353500369382
      10005 |                9353500238058
      10006 |                9353500205141
      10007 |                9353500297414
      10008 |                9353500286020
      10009 |                9353500219563
      10010 |                9353500443892
```

And also test the reverse function:

```
SELECT
    card_number, employee_id_from_card_number(card_number)
FROM
    generate_series(9353500001234 + 1023, 9353500001234 + 1023 + 9) AS s(card_number);
```

```
  card_number | employee_id_from_card_number
------------: | ---------------------------:
9353500002257 |                        46754
9353500002258 |                        25124
9353500002259 |                       481462
9353500002260 |                        99475
9353500002261 |                       173732
9353500002262 |                       171043
9353500002263 |                       245192
9353500002264 |                       418200
9353500002265 |                        76374
9353500002266 |                       251095
```

You can check all the setup and functions at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=938302afa29044cb3141a7af4293738c)*

Comment: in your example you have generated the employee_id also.
In my case its available in a table. 
how to modify the insert statement such that it picks from below table and populate
select employee_number from employee

I want the below insert statement to insert employee_id from the employee table    

  `INSERT INTO employee_card (employee_id, card_number)
SELECT
    row_number() over(order by random()) AS employee_id, employee_card
FROM
    -- generate card_numbers
    generate_series(9353500001234, 9353500501234) AS s(employee_card)`

Comment: update employee
    set gs1_src_acct_num = e2.new_gs1_src_acct_num
    from (select e2.*,
                 (row_number() over (order by random()) - 1 + 9353500001234) as new_gs1_src_acct_num
          from employee e2
         ) e2
     where e2.member_number = e.member_number;  I would use something like above to do a one time update.